# How to build boost using VS10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, boost-regex, vc10

I have an issue with compiling Boost using VC:
error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib'

The most interesting is that issue is observed only using VC10 compiler.
MinGW builds successfully Boost regex.

Does anybody know how to fix it ?

PS: I cannot use b2, bjam and etc., because I have retrieved part of boost regex using bcp module, and I need to compile it using VC10 and CMake.

Comment: Boost never supported the build of CMake.

Comment: @  usr1234567: Boost does not support build by CMake, but I have separated a regex by **bcp** module and compiled this module successfully by **MinGW**.

Comment: I don't understand. You have modified Boost, now it does not work, and we should help, without knowing your modifications?

Comment: instead of rebuild boost by yourself, why not to take an [official prebuilt binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.53.0/)?

Comment: @usr1234567: No, I have not modify Boost. I've just retrieved the part of Boost regex and integrated it in my project.
For motre information see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @zaufi: Because I test my code on Windows, but after it should work on Linux system. And I do not want to depend on prebuilt binaries. I just want that little part of Boost be builded and it works with MinGW compiler, but when I try to use VC10 due to some dependency on flags and so on it tries to find 'libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib'

Comment: @ДенисКотов, I guess your target Linux distro have boost packages, so why to to use them? Just make a native package of your software and add dependency on required boost packages (`libboost-regex` I guess)...

Comment: If you are using CMake just use boost finder it provides. It is quite flexible and cross-platform and would find boost installation everywhere. Also CPack could helps you to make a native package of your software.

Comment: I have found solution something like this -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB, but it does not work. I do not understand why only VC10 compiler tries to find this library ('libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib') as at the same time MinGW compiles all properly. Maybe some special flags I need to set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed an issue. Just added at the top level CMakeLists.txt file:

add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )

Thanks, all who participate in helping me.